# Как разграничить запросы по разным провайдерам?

Tags: windows, route

Есть два провайдера.
Есть ли программы либо код, что б запросы на одни ip адреса шли к одному провайдеру, а другие- к другому провайдеру?  Тем самым приблизив скорость скачивания торрентов к сумме скорости обеих провайдеров.
ОС Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Если для Windows то можно использовать [Trafаic Inspector](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4124447)

хотя я бы не советовал, лучше воспользоватся хардварным решением на базе Mikrotik, там это реализуется очень просто и главное без глюков

Вся суть процесса сводится к настройке 2х каналов интернета,настройки NAT, удалить шлюз по умолчанию, и назначить в качестве шлюзов эти 2 канала в зависимости от пропускной способности.

192.168.1.249 - 1шлюз
192.168.222.1 - 2шлюз

вариант для балансировки 50/50

```
 ip route add dst-address=0.0.0.0/0 gateway=192.168.1.249,192.168.222.1
```

Предположим, что у первого провайдера скорость доступа в два раза выше чем у второго, тогда 2/3 исходящих запросов надо направить на первого, а оставшиеся 1/3 на второго.

```
 ip route add dst-address=0.0.0.0/0
gateway=192.168.1.249,192.168.1.249,192.168.222.1
```

[Полное описание процесса настройки](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4124447)

[Более развёрнуто о способах балансировки нагрузки](http://mum.mikrotik.com/presentations/UA12/lukin.pdf)

ПС. Однако всякого рода Http, Https, ftp и тому подобный трафик нужно будет маркировать и направлять ручками (или возможно используя скрипты)) на определённый канал дабы исключить вариант смены IP при обновлении страниц к примеру

Answer (score 0):

> Есть ли программы либо код, что б запросы на одни ip адреса шли к одному провайдеру, а другие- к другому провайдеру?

```
route -p add x.x.x.x mask y.y.y.y z.z.z.z
```

где x.x.x.x mask y.y.y.y - это подсеть тех самых "одних адресов", а z.z.z.z - выданный этим "одинм провайдером" адрес для дефолтного шлюза. При этом сам дефолтный шлюз на сетевой карте к этому провайдеру следует убрать.